# Error de datatable a leer datos Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

Tengo el siguiente codigo para agregar jquery a mi tabla y tenga mas herramientas, lo que pasa es que cuando inicio la aplicacion aveces funciona y aveces no, cuando no funciona recargo la pagina hasta que ya queda, obviamente esa no es la idea , los datos son obtenidos de una consulta hacia un servidor alojado en clever cloud.

```
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
<title>GestAPP</title>
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../static/css/style.css">
```

```
    <ul class="head">
      <h1 class="title">Gestion de casos</h1>
    </ul>
    <table class="display" id="tableCasos">
        <thead>
        <tr class="headtable">
          <th class="date1">Caso</h>
          <th class="date1">Nombre</th>
          <th class="date1">Numero</th>
          <th class="date1">Localidad</th>
          <th class="date1">Direccion</th>
          <th class="date1">Afectacion</th>
          <th class="date1">Estado</th>
          <th class="date1">Operacion</th>
        </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody  id='casos'>
        </tbody>
    </table>


<footer>
  <h3>@Maicol Avila</h3>
</footer>
<script type="text/javascript" src="app.js"></script>
<link
    rel="stylesheet"
    href="../views/jquery.dataTables.min.css"
/>
<script src="../jquery-3.5.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="../jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<script>
    if (window.module) module = window.module;
</script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(async function () {
        await $('#tableCasos').DataTable({   
      });   
  });  
</script>
```

*

Comment: Hola bienvenido, prueba cambiando el orden en el que importas los scripts

<script src="../jquery-3.5.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="../jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="app.js"></script>

Primero jQuery, luego dataTables, y por último app.js;
También por convención todos los css deberían aparecer arriba (en el head)

Comment: Hola gracias por la ayuda, ya lo intente y no funciono. Haciendo unas pruebas anoche me di cuenta que el problema se da por la lentitud del hosting ya que cuando la base la tengo almacenada en localhost funciona a la perfeccion, la cuestion es que de momento tengo que usar ese hosting gratiuto. Entonces no se como hacer que la aplicacion no cargue hasta que todas las consultas esten listas.